# Navigator 2 using bloc in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, navigation

I'm trying to implement Navigator 2 technique with the bloc.
with out using third party library and which is more extensible and more generic in nature easy to test modules
How to implement Navigator 2 using bloc patter in flutter?

Comment: Try reading and implementing the examples here to start https://bloclibrary.dev/#/recipesflutternavigation

Comment: @VipinKumarKashyap thanks that were an awesome one, could you please help me on handling the deep link